# Why is it that modifying lists in functions changes the original list, but declaring them in a function creates a new object?

Tags: python

I'm new to writing code, and I understand the behavior of lists to an extent. Whenever a list is modified within a function's scope, the one in global scope changes too.

For example,

```
def modify_list(lst):
    lst.append(5)

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

#This output is [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(lst)

modify_list(lst)

#This output is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] because of the function.
print(lst)
```

I don't understand why this example won't work:

```
def modify_list(lst):
    lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

#Output is [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(lst)

modify_list(lst)

#Output is [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(lst)
```

Why doesn't `lst` get modified in the second example? Is it because I'm creating a new object within the function's scope? Using the global keyword works instead of passing a parameter, but I want to avoid using global unless absolutely necessary.

I'm using this in an initialization function and want to revert the list back to its original state whenever the function is called. Again, using global works, I'm just wondering why this doesn't work.
Thanks! (Sorry if I'm not good at explaining things well)

Comment: The `lst` inside the function scope just live there and the function itself it's doing nothing to the input. If you want the function to return the list inside the scope you should add `return lst`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function comes in handy here. Basically, the `id` function returns an integer that is guaranteed to be unique and constant for the lifetime of whatever object it was called on. In fact, in CPython (regular Python), `id` returns the address of the object in memory.

So if you run your code, printing the id of `lst` before and after running your `modify_list`, you'll find that the id changes when you assign to `lst` but not when you append.

Calling append on `lst` won't change the id of `lst` because lists in Python are *mutable*, and appending simply *mutates* the list. But, when you assign `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` to `lst`, you are creating a brand-new list object and assigning it to `lst`. This is not a mutation, and doesn't change the original in anyway. In general in Python, you can mutate arguments within a function to modify the original copy, but assigning a new object to it is not a mutation and won't change the original copy.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
def modify_list(lst):
    lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

you make local variable `lst` point to a completely different object than the one you passed as the argument in `modify_list(lst)` call. Maybe this article will help you understand: https://medium.com/school-of-code/passing-by-assignment-in-python-7c829a2df10a

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I understand. To clarify, the list I'm assigning to the variable in the function is a different object than the list I'm assigning to the variable in the global scope. Thanks for the article